# Python Residential Proxy

Tags: python, networking, proxy, network-programming

Here is my problem I managed to redirect the traffic via a python script which listens on port 80 of the pc the problem is when I want to access from outside the residence the client's proxy server so I am looking for a way to do not open ports like packetStream does

```py
class ProxyHandler(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_CONNECT(self):
        self.send_response(200, "Connection reussi")
        self.send_header("Proxy-agent", "Python Proxy")
        self.end_headers()

        with self.connect_to_target() as target_client:
            self.exchange_loop(self.connection, target_client)

    def connect_to_target(self):
        target_host, target_port = self.path.split(":")
        target_port = int(target_port)

        target_client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        target_client.connect((target_host, target_port))
        return target_client

    def exchange_loop(self, client, remote):
        while True:
            data = client.recv(4096)
            if not data:
                break
            remote.sendall(data)

        client.close()
        remote.close()


def on_exit():
    # Code à exécuter avant la sortie du programme
    #sendState(False)
    print("Le programme est en train de se terminer.")


# Enregistrement de la fonction on_exit pour être appelée à la sortie du programme
atexit.register(on_exit)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    handler = ProxyHandler
    with socketserver.ThreadingTCPServer(("localhost", PORT), handler) as httpd:
        #sendState(True)
        print(f"HTTP Proxy server is running on http://localhost:{PORT}")
        httpd.serve_forever()
```